# How do I re-use the same Python application in Phusion-Passenger from different virtual hosts but maintaining separate processes?

Tags: python, django, apache2, passenger, virtualhost

I have two virtual hosts that serve the same Django application using Apache and Passenger:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName A
    SetEnv V "VA"
    DocumentRoot /path/public
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName B
    SetEnv V "VB"
    DocumentRoot /path/public
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Since the DocRoot is the same for both, the first time Passenger starts/spawns a process the ENV variable will be set depending on the first virtualhost requested. The application code is then cached and so, even visiting the other vhost, the ENV variable will still be the one set at spawn time.

Now, by reading the docs, I thought that setting `PassengerSpawnMethod` to "direct" would solve the problem, but apparently it doesn't. I'm curious to know why and what is "direct" doing and also how would I solve this problem?

My end goal is to pass different env variables from the vhost to the same exact Django application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PassengerAppGroupName. Give each one a different name.